# setContent is not working for NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to show a custom layout as a notification in a service.

here is my method in the Service class:

```
private void fireNotification() {
    Log.d("Clock", "Fire!");
    if (this.remoteViews == null) {
        Log.d("Clock", "!=null");

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContent(
                remoteViews);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

custom_notification.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

But the default notification shows up with my Icon!
What's worng?

EDIT:
I ran my app on an emulator and it's working on Android 4 but in my phone with gingerbread it's not working!

Comment: show your custom_layout code here

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your desired image to the image view what is there in custom_layout

```
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Then what is the problem with that.

Comment: I think it about the API level. It's working in android 4 but not in 2.3.x

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google's bug list page](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30495), the NotificationCompat.Builder doesn't support setContent on Android 2.x.

Possible workaround from the bug page (#6):

`notification = builder.build();
notification.contentView = contentView;`